# Converting Day of the Year to a date when some date formats have DDYYYY and some have DDDYYYY in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

So I am trying to convert some Day of the Year dates to Date format. The problem is some day of the year dates are in DDYYYY format for days under 100 and DDDYYYY format for days 100 and over. I have tried the following but still receive a "day of year must be between 1 and 365 (366 for leap year)" error:

```
select CASE when data_Date >= 999999
        then to_date(data_date, 'DDDYYYY')
        when data_Date >= 99999
        then to_date(data_Date, 'DDYYYY')
        else to_date(data_date, 'DYYYY')
    END                 as         DATA_DATE_CONVERTED
 from table;
```

Thanks in advance

Sample Data is as follows:

```
Data_date (being passed in as a varchar2)

1072015
12017
612014
672013
72017
1112018
```

Comment: Some sample data would be helpful.

Comment: sorry, added it!

Comment: You do understand the reason your attempt failed, right? The different models ('DDYYYY' and 'DYYYY') have very different meaning from 'DDDYYYY' - they don't just mean the "day" component has only two digits, or one. By comparison, if your inputs were in the format 4-2017, 53-2017 etc. and you gave the format model 'DDD-YYYY', that would work without problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last 4 digit is the year. Use `LPAD` to put leading zeroes on DAY

```
select  to_date( lpad(dayyear, 7, '0'),'DDDYYYY')  
from table;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71956/3)

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
with demo (data_date) as
     ( select 1072015 from dual union all
       select 12017 from dual union all
       select 612014 from dual union all
       select 672013 from dual union all
       select 72017 from dual union all
       select 1112018 from dual )
select data_date
     , to_char(data_date,'0000000')
     , to_date(to_char(data_date,'0000000'),'DDDYYYY') as data_date_converted
from   demo
```

Comment: Nice answer. If we don't call `TO_CHAR` on the input number explicitly, Big Brother Oracle will do it for us anyway. So why not call it explicitly, give it the format model that fits our needs, and not have to touch the resulting string after that? +1

Answer (score 0):

You can also put a dash (-) between.

```
with demo (data_date) as
     ( select 1072015 from dual union all
       select 12017 from dual union all
       select 612014 from dual union all
       select 672013 from dual union all
       select 72017 from dual union all
       select 1112018 from dual )
select data_date, TO_DATE(SUBSTR(data_date, 1, length(data_date)-4)||'-'||SUBSTR(data_date, -4, 4), 'DDD-YYYY')
  from demo;
```